# PostgreSQL giving different plan/index results when running query direct vs via Java App

Tags: postgresql

I am monitoring queries that are > than 1 second on our postgresql 9.5 server. I get a particular query that comes up when its run from a Java App that takes over 2 seconds to complete.

When I extract that query from the postgresql log and run it directly against the postgresql DB it only takes 17ms roughly. I have added in additional explains log analyze buffer etc. But cannot figure out why it would be taking so long via the Java app but only milliseconds when run direct.

I have got the output of the explain analyze verbose buffers json below:

```
{
  "Query Text": " select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as \"CAPABILITY\" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME=$1 and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>$2) and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID=$3",
  "Plan": {
    "Node Type": "Aggregate",
    "Strategy": "Hashed",
    "Startup Cost": 78.41,
    "Total Cost": 78.45,
    "Plan Rows": 4,
    "Plan Width": 19,
    "Actual Startup Time": 2345.849,
    "Actual Total Time": 2346.038,
    "Actual Rows": 1062,
    "Actual Loops": 1,
    "Output": ["sc.capability_name"],
    "Group Key": ["sc.capability_name"],
    "Shared Hit Blocks": 1740151,
    "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
    "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
    "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
    "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
    "Local Read Blocks": 0,
    "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
    "Local Written Blocks": 0,
    "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
    "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
    "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
    "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
    "Plans": [
      {
        "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
        "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
        "Join Type": "Inner",
        "Startup Cost": 5.49,
        "Total Cost": 78.40,
        "Plan Rows": 4,
        "Plan Width": 19,
        "Actual Startup Time": 20.205,
        "Actual Total Time": 2344.449,
        "Actual Rows": 2310,
        "Actual Loops": 1,
        "Output": ["sc.capability_name"],
        "Shared Hit Blocks": 1740151,
        "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
        "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
        "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
        "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
        "Local Read Blocks": 0,
        "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
        "Local Written Blocks": 0,
        "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
        "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
        "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
        "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
        "Plans": [
          {
            "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
            "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
            "Join Type": "Inner",
            "Startup Cost": 5.22,
            "Total Cost": 77.12,
            "Plan Rows": 4,
            "Plan Width": 38,
            "Actual Startup Time": 20.194,
            "Actual Total Time": 2331.617,
            "Actual Rows": 2310,
            "Actual Loops": 1,
            "Output": ["urc.capability", "grc.capability"],
            "Join Filter": "((gu.role)::text = (urc.role_name)::text)",
            "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 1568706,
            "Shared Hit Blocks": 1733203,
            "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
            "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
            "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
            "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
            "Local Read Blocks": 0,
            "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
            "Local Written Blocks": 0,
            "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
            "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
            "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
            "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
            "Plans": [
              {
                "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                "Join Type": "Inner",
                "Startup Cost": 4.93,
                "Total Cost": 62.56,
                "Plan Rows": 30,
                "Plan Width": 36,
                "Actual Startup Time": 0.148,
                "Actual Total Time": 103.202,
                "Actual Rows": 288368,
                "Actual Loops": 1,
                "Output": ["grc.capability", "gu.role"],
                "Shared Hit Blocks": 12643,
                "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
                "Plans": [
                  {
                    "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                    "Join Type": "Inner",
                    "Startup Cost": 0.42,
                    "Total Cost": 9.82,
                    "Plan Rows": 1,
                    "Plan Width": 85,
                    "Actual Startup Time": 0.023,
                    "Actual Total Time": 2.488,
                    "Actual Rows": 268,
                    "Actual Loops": 1,
                    "Output": ["gu.role", "gr.role_name"],
                    "Shared Hit Blocks": 315,
                    "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                    "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                    "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                    "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                    "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
                    "Plans": [
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Index Only Scan",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                        "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                        "Index Name": "idx_gp_usr_gp_usrnm_rl_exp_dt",
                        "Relation Name": "group_user",
                        "Schema": "TEST",
                        "Alias": "gu",
                        "Startup Cost": 0.42,
                        "Total Cost": 8.46,
                        "Plan Rows": 1,
                        "Plan Width": 26,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 0.017,
                        "Actual Total Time": 0.518,
                        "Actual Rows": 268,
                        "Actual Loops": 1,
                        "Output": ["gu.group_id", "gu.username", "gu.role", "gu.expiry_date"],
                        "Index Cond": "((gu.group_id = ($3)::text) AND (gu.username = ($1)::text))",
                        "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                        "Filter": "((gu.expiry_date IS NULL) OR (gu.expiry_date > $2))",
                        "Rows Removed by Filter": 0,
                        "Heap Fetches": 268,
                        "Shared Hit Blocks": 47,
                        "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                        "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                        "I/O Write Time": 0.000
                      },
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                        "Relation Name": "group_role",
                        "Schema": "TEST",
                        "Alias": "gr",
                        "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                        "Total Cost": 1.35,
                        "Plan Rows": 1,
                        "Plan Width": 112,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 0.003,
                        "Actual Total Time": 0.005,
                        "Actual Rows": 1,
                        "Actual Loops": 268,
                        "Output": ["gr.id", "gr.role_name"],
                        "Filter": "((gr.id)::text = ($3)::text)",
                        "Rows Removed by Filter": 27,
                        "Shared Hit Blocks": 268,
                        "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                        "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                        "I/O Write Time": 0.000
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
                    "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                    "Relation Name": "role_capability",
                    "Schema": "TEST",
                    "Alias": "grc",
                    "Startup Cost": 4.51,
                    "Total Cost": 52.44,
                    "Plan Rows": 30,
                    "Plan Width": 33,
                    "Actual Startup Time": 0.096,
                    "Actual Total Time": 0.229,
                    "Actual Rows": 1076,
                    "Actual Loops": 268,
                    "Output": ["grc.role_name", "grc.capability"],
                    "Recheck Cond": "((grc.role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)",
                    "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                    "Exact Heap Blocks": 10184,
                    "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
                    "Shared Hit Blocks": 12328,
                    "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                    "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                    "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                    "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                    "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                    "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                    "I/O Write Time": 0.000,
                    "Plans": [
                      {
                        "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                        "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                        "Index Name": "pk_role_capability",
                        "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                        "Total Cost": 4.51,
                        "Plan Rows": 30,
                        "Plan Width": 0,
                        "Actual Startup Time": 0.091,
                        "Actual Total Time": 0.091,
                        "Actual Rows": 1076,
                        "Actual Loops": 268,
                        "Index Cond": "((grc.role_name)::text = (gr.role_name)::text)",
                        "Shared Hit Blocks": 2144,
                        "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                        "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                        "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                        "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                        "I/O Write Time": 0.000
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                "Index Name": "idx_role_capability_capability",
                "Relation Name": "role_capability",
                "Schema": "TEST",
                "Alias": "urc",
                "Startup Cost": 0.28,
                "Total Cost": 0.42,
                "Plan Rows": 5,
                "Plan Width": 33,
                "Actual Startup Time": 0.005,
                "Actual Total Time": 0.007,
                "Actual Rows": 5,
                "Actual Loops": 288368,
                "Output": ["urc.role_name", "urc.capability"],
                "Index Cond": "((urc.capability)::text = (grc.capability)::text)",
                "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                "Shared Hit Blocks": 1720560,
                "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
                "I/O Write Time": 0.000
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Node Type": "Index Only Scan",
            "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
            "Scan Direction": "Forward",
            "Index Name": "idx_system_capability_capability_name",
            "Relation Name": "system_capability",
            "Schema": "TEST",
            "Alias": "sc",
            "Startup Cost": 0.28,
            "Total Cost": 0.31,
            "Plan Rows": 1,
            "Plan Width": 19,
            "Actual Startup Time": 0.005,
            "Actual Total Time": 0.005,
            "Actual Rows": 1,
            "Actual Loops": 2310,
            "Output": ["sc.capability_name"],
            "Index Cond": "(sc.capability_name = (urc.capability)::text)",
            "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
            "Heap Fetches": 2310,
            "Shared Hit Blocks": 6948,
            "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
            "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
            "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
            "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
            "Local Read Blocks": 0,
            "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
            "Local Written Blocks": 0,
            "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
            "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
            "I/O Read Time": 0.000,
            "I/O Write Time": 0.000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Triggers": [
  ]
}
```

Query is also below:

```
 select distinct sc.CAPABILITY_NAME as "CAPABILITY" from SYSTEM_CAPABILITY sc join ROLE_CAPABILITY urc on urc.CAPABILITY=sc.CAPABILITY_NAME join ROLE_CAPABILITY grc on grc.CAPABILITY=urc.CAPABILITY join GROUP_USER gu on gu.ROLE=urc.ROLE_NAME join GROUP_ROLE gr on gr.ROLE_NAME=grc.ROLE_NAME where gu.USERNAME=$1 and (gu.EXPIRY_DATE is null or gu.EXPIRY_DATE>$2) and gr.ID=gu.GROUP_ID and gu.GROUP_ID=$3
```

Does anybody know why postgres would behave in such a way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you run it from a client tool like DBweaver or pgadmin ?

Comment: @RajVerma Sorry should of said I am running the query direct via DBeaver. It runs in milliseconds (17 approx).

Comment: When you explain analyze the query that is the time on postgres "Server Side" to execute the query, this time does not include the time to transfer the results back to the app, or API, service etc. Does that explain your situation ?

Comment: @RajVerma when I use an online website which allows you to read the explain analyze verbose it says there is an index only scan which has the following: Timing: 2s 019ms | 86%
Rows: 5 (Planned: 5)
Cost: 0.42 (Total: 0.42)
Loops: 288368, am hoping its an issue with the Java App, but when I compare the explains they both give different plans/results. Could this be because of the Java App?

Comment: ok i guess there is some gap here, you are saying that the plans are different for the same query whilst running it from 2 different tools or the time taken by the query with the same plan is different ?

Comment: @RajVerma plans are different for the exact same query. From the Java app which total time is 2 seconds it uses a different join, I think a nested loop, where as when running via Dbeaver, it uses a hashed join at the start.

Comment: do you mind running a vacuum analyze verbose and then re run the query from both DBweaver and java apps and share the results ?

Comment: No JSON execution plans. But we need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. For the Java, execution, `auto_explain` will help.

Comment: @RajVerma ran the vacuum analyze verbose, < 2020-12-11 11:39:02.134 CET >LOG:  duration: 142935.351 ms  execute <unnamed>: vacuum analyze verbose (updated 0 rows)
Running the script via DBeaver took 242ms, running via App I now dont see the issue (we monitor queries > 1 second and would usually see this). As a maintenance task we usually run a vacuum full (./vacuumdb -f -a). Does Vacuum analyze differ to a vacuum full ?

Comment: I would suggest do some reading on analyze, also to give you the short version you use it to update stats, however vacuum is more of a cleanup for dead rows(tuples), essentially the combination of both does the cleanup and updation of stats, vacuum full locks the table for the duration of the run, don’t DO it!

Comment: @RajVerma Thanks for the quick response. This is a performance environment so we regularly take updates and do backups/restores so are in a position to do this. Am seeing much better results now. Will do some reading on analyze, isnt doing a normal vacuum only marking rows for deletion but vacuum full actually removes those dead tuples. Thanks again

Comment: Nope vacuum gives space back for reuse to pg, full gives it back to the os!